# Data Frame for Function Result

Tags: r, dataframe

I use loop for a function,

```
AllModel <- AllData[c(2:8)]
alladvancedfit <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=7, ncol=1))
for (Model in AllModel) {
  advancedfit.model <- Arima(AllData$x1,order=c(0,1,2),xreg=Model)
  inSampleAdvancedFitMAE <- mean(abs(advancedfit.model$residuals))
  }
```

AllModel capture this data set

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
1   39  4   84  75  41  6   83
2   40  6   86  77  44  6   84
3   39  5   82  73  40  6   81
4   37  5   100 71  39  6   90
5   39  5   83  70  37  5   79
6   44  6   82  78  40  6   78
7   41  5   76  76  40  7   78
8   40  5   74  72  42  6   81
```

And the result is lists of output.

```
[1] 61.01004
[1] 61.23916
[1] 60.78099
[1] 61.15394
[1] 61.16968
[1] 61.30191
[1] 61.00637
```

Would like to put this into one data frame. Try to rbind it inside the loop but so far it is unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you show the code where you tried to `rbind`? Also why use `rbind` when you already prepared an empty data.frame `alladvancedfit ` to receive the results? (Which, btw. **is** the correct way to do what you want)

Comment: for (Model in AllModel) {
  advancedfit.model <- Arima(AllData$x1,order=c(0,1,2),xreg=Model)
  inSampleAdvancedFitMAE <- mean(abs(advancedfit.model$residuals))
  inSampleAdvancedFitMAE <- rbind(inSampleAdvancedFitMAE,alladvancedfit)
    }
so which method are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always helpful if you'd provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

I'm assuming `allModel` is a list

1.Initialize data.frame to receive results:

```
alladvancedfit <- data.frame(mean_residuals = rep(NA, lenght(allModel)))
```

2.Loop through the models and fill in the summary information into `alladvancedfit`

```
for (i in seq_along(AllModel)) {
  advancedfit.model <- Arima(AllData$x1,order=c(0,1,2),xreg=AllModel[i])
  alladvancedfit$mean_residuals[i] <- mean(abs(advancedfit.model$residuals))
}
```

Comment: already put the AllModel dataset on the question section. I'm trying to do your code but there's a warning - Error in Arima(AllData$x1, order = c(0, 1, 2), xreg = AllModel[i]) : xreg should be a numeric matrix or a numeric vector

Comment: Still don't know the class and type of `AllModel`. You could check the links i provided if you would like to learn how to provide a MRE... With regard to your error: Since `AllModel` in your data is not a list it should probably be `seq_along(AllModel[1,])` and `xreg=AllModel[, i]`)

Comment: yes change the code into seq_along(AllModel[1,]) and it works fine now. thank you!

Comment: Have a bug free day ;)